# Condition TRUE or FALSE output based on TIME of day. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, logic

Consider a store that open at 9:15AM and closes at 3:30PM. Based on the urrent time i would like to print if the Store is Open or Closed.
I am having difficulty with the logic. In my code if the time is 9:45AM the output is Closed.

```
import time
timenow = time.localtime()
print(timenow)
print(timenow.tm_hour)
print(timenow.tm_min)
if ((timenow.tm_hour >= 9) & (timenow.tm_min >= 15)):
    if((timenow.tm_hour <= 15) & (timenow.tm_min <= 30)):
        print('Store open.')
    else:
        print('Store closed.')
```

If there is a better way to do this, i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? Does it not work?

Comment: there are major gaps when the condition fails when it is supposed to be true, for example when its 9:45AM the output is False.

Comment: @SouravB.Roy Please check my code review under, hope it will help you improve your skills and avoid errors in future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** you work with the time module. Which in this case is not the best solution below I will explain why. The time module in most cases calls the C library of the platform host. That is, the behavior and results of the same function will be different on different operating systems.

**Secondly**, the code does not use the time zone, which of course will lead to gross application errors.

Example:

```
In [38]: time.localtime()
Out[38]: time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=16, tm_hour=5, tm_min=56, tm_sec=49, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=47, tm_isdst=0)
```

Displays in GMT but my actual time is

```
root@xxx# date
Fri Feb 16 13:57:55 +08 2018
```

Here we meet with **timezones**.

> A time zone is a region of the globe that observes a uniform standard time for legal, commercial, and social purposes. Time zones tend to follow the boundaries of countries and their subdivisions because it is convenient for areas in close commercial or other communication to keep the same time.

In Python the best approach to work with time and dates it's **datetime** module for operations and **pytz** for timezones.

Pytz doesn't standard Python's lib, so don't forget to install it

```
pip install pytz
```

> There are two kinds of date and time objects: “naive” and “aware”.
>
> An **aware** object has sufficient knowledge of applicable algorithmic and political time adjustments, such as time zone and daylight saving time information, to locate itself relative to other aware objects. An aware object is used to represent a specific moment in time that is not open to interpretation.
>
> A **naive** object does not contain enough information to unambiguously locate itself relative to other date/time objects. Whether a naive object represents Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), local time, or time in some other timezone is purely up to the program, just like it is up to the program whether a particular number represents metres, miles, or mass. Naive objects are easy to understand and to work with, at the cost of ignoring some aspects of reality

And in real world application we always work with "aware" datetime objects.

Example:

```
import datetime
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('Singapore')
datetime.datetime.now(tz)
datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 16, 14, 15, 6, 822038, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Singapore' +08+8:00:00 STD>)
```

Now we have correct time with a proper timezone. We don't need to take care about operations under datetime objects.

> For example, you want to show the flight time of Singapore-Bangkok. Time difference between SNG and BKK timezones is 1 hour. So when 14:00 in Singapore it's 13:00 in Bangkok. All airlines adhere to the same rule. Time of departure and arrival are indicated in the local time with timezone GMT offset. Let's assume what the real flight time between SNG and BKK is 1 hour we will have SNG departure 14:00 +8 - BKK arrival 14:00 +7.
>   So, in a case if we ignore timezones difference between departure and arrival
>   will be 0 hours hence and our displaying flight time will be 0 hours. That is a mistake of course. Also don't forget about DST rules, leap years and etc. But if you use datetime "aware" objects you don't have to worry about anything.

Summing up all the above, let's rewrite our code

```
import datetime

import pytz


def shop_is_open(tz='Singapore'):
    tz = pytz.timezone(tz)
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now(tz).time()

    #here we could apply any timezone according shop geo location
    time_open = datetime.time(9, 45, tzinfo=tz)
    time_close = datetime.time(15, 30, tzinfo=tz)

    is_open = False

    if time_now >= time_open and time_now <= time_close:
        is_open = True

    return is_open
```

Comment: greetings @Denis really great answer. There is no scope for doubt. I would have never thought of factoring in timezone. This answer taught me how to think like a real programmer. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

I came up with a very simple and non fancy code. I could just comment it but I still don't have enough reputation for that. Just convert your hour to minutes like this

```
import time

def time_to_min(hour, minute):
    return hour*60+minute

timenow = time.localtime()

open_time = time_to_min(9, 15)
close_time = time_to_min(15, 30)
current_time = time_to_min(timenow.tm_hour, timenow.tm_min)

if current_time >= open_time and current_time <= close_time:
    print 'Store opened'
else:
    print 'Store closed'
```

Comment: it is simple but does not work after interchanging values  it always shows store closed

Answer (score 0):

Using datetime, which i find easier:

```
import datetime

# define the opening hours
startTime = datetime.time(9, 15, 0)
endTime = datetime.time(15, 30, 0)

# function that compares the given time against opening and closing
def isOpen(startTime, endTime, x):
    if startTime <= endTime:
        return startTime <= x <= endTime
    else:
        return startTime <= x or x <= endTime

# Call isOpen function ( datetime.time is the "current time" )
print isOpen(startTime, endTime, datetime.time(14, 30, 0))
print isOpen(startTime, endTime, datetime.time(20, 30, 0))
```

If you want to run it against the current time just call the function like so:

```
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now().time()
print isOpen(startTime, endTime, currentTime)
```